# Borel Measures and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a problem from my real analysis class:

> Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $V$ be a nonempty, bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, define $V+x = \left\lbrace v+x : v \in V \right\rbrace$. Define $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \mu(V+x)$. Is $f$ necessarily continuous?

My initial thought is no, $f$ does not have to be continuous (just right-continuous?) but I've been trying to come up with a counterexample. It seemed easiest to just let $V$ be something simple like $V=(0,1)$. Also it seemed logical to pick a Borel measure associated with a Distribution function since I'm more familiar with Distribution Functions, so I would think something like this $f$ would work as a counterexample:

$$f(x) = 0, x < \frac{1}{2}$$ $$f(x) = 1, x \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

So $\mu$ is still finite, and $f$ naturally has a discontinuity at $x=\frac{1}{2}$... everything is just getting shifted over which should preserve the discontinuity. I feel like there's a number of technical details I'm not expressing properly, so my argument doesn't feel sound.

Comment: Take $x_0 \in V$ and $\mu = \delta_{x_0}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct to choose $\mu$ to be a delta measure is a good one.
The function $x\mapsto \delta_{1/2}\left(V+x\right)$ can only take 2 possible values. Is this a continuous function?

Comment: Ah, ok I see I was on the right track but overthinking it a bit more than I needed to. Thank you!